# Why there is a "static" keywoard in static pointer return function?

Tags: c++

I am getting difficult time understand why there is a keyworad "static" in header only (I understand what that code does and how to use it in API

```
//Header
class A 
{
    static A * create();
    bool init();

};


A* A::create()
{
    A * ob = new (std::nothrow) A();
    if(A && a->init()){
        A->autorealease();
        return A;
    }
    SAFE_DELETE(A);
    return nullptr;
}
```

Used like this `A* testobj = A::create();` (Which will go out of scope if it's not saved in some (vector) array, thus it will be cleaned by the engine).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question... What are you asking exactly?

Comment: You only need `static` in the function declaration - it says this function does not require a class instance for it to be called on.

Comment: My apologize if I wrote it wrong. But I am askign the reason of using "Static" pointer instead of just returning pointer.

Comment: There is no "static pointer", it's the function that is static.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - Thank you for explanation, now I understand it.

Comment: You really should pick up a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am askign the reason of using `static` pointer instead of just returning pointer

The member function is static, but the pointer it returns is not. The object the function creates is allocated dynamically, and should be deleted in the same way that you delete other objects.

The reason the member function is marked `static` is to let you run it without creating an instance of the object, i.e.

```
A* myObj = A::create();
```

as opposed to

```
A obj;
A* objPtr = obj.create();
```

which defeats the purpose of defining a factory function in the first place.

Keyword `static` is not repeated at the point the member function is defined in accordance with C++ syntax: the compiler already knows from the declaration that `A::create` is `static`, so there is no need to repeat this information.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth adding that `static` used outside a class definition has a totally different meaning (internal linkage).